# Best way to resize a Word template with many features?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been given some A4 templates with a lot of funky features (odd & even margins, logos, text boxes, tables, header footer, sidebar image in the footer etc) that I've been asked to work on. I need to resize them to various other page sizes e.g letter, A3 and so on. I've done a few by going ahead with the basic page setup - change size but it leaves a lot of manual tinkering to get objects to sit properly on the page again and the margins don't seem to scale with the new page size.

Are there any pointers to gracefully scaling a document?

I'm using Word 2016.

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately there is no automatic way for that, you need to check everything and adapt manually. Especially because you're not scaling everything (e.g. A4 -> A6 doesn't mean you also decrease font size by 50%).

Answer (score 0):

Margin widths don't scale, but if you align things like text boxes and images relative to, e.g., the margins instead of at absolute positions on the page, and if you specify the width of tables, and the width and/or height of text boxes and background images as percentages of the margin, page, or column width/height, the template will adapt somewhat gracefully to changes in paper size.

I've used this approach to design a single template that was used by project members in both the US and Europe, so documents needed to look good regardless of whether they were written in/printed on Letter or A4 paper sizes.